# Backup and Restore MySQL database

Tags: windows, mysql, database-backup

need backup MySQL 5.1 databse. Database is install on Windows Server 2003. I google it and I found many tools but I am little confuse what choose.

My requirments are:

- Tool for backup must have a GUI
- It would be good if support only backup, without shutdown database
- It must run under windows
- I would like only choose MySQL folder source and destination folder for backup, second setup time 
  when start backup. For example once time at week.
- option for restore data from backup

Do you have good suggestion for me?

Answer (score 5):

Backups of MySQL are normally done via the command line but if you really want a GUI interface you could use something like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/), which allows you to export and import your data as eithe CSV or SQL files, which you can place wherever you like.

I do recommend that you learn to use the command line tools, such as `mysqldump` as that will allow you to automate these things, which is how backups should be run.